# Installing and using pyperclip in Thonny IDE

Tags: python, thonny

I've been trying to learn python using Automate the Boring Stuff with Python (has not been as easy as I would have liked). In chapter 6, the author is using a module he created for a project. I seemingly installed the module successfully, but I'm getting the following error when I run his sample code:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('Hello, world!')
pyperclip.paste()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\16463\OneDrive\Desktop\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

I'm using Thonny IDE.

Comment: what command did you use in your terminal; are you using an IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: I am using a program called Thonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Look at **Update #1** below for the answer.*

---

You need to install the `pyperclip` module before using it.

In your terminal, execute the following command to install `pyperclip`.

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Reference:

- https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/
- https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

---

**UPDATE #1**

I see that in one of your comments you said that you are using **Thonny IDE**.

You can install packages in Thonny IDE from *Tools -> Manage Packages*. There you can search for required packages and *install* them.

Comment: i did that already, just did it again and got the following msg: Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\16463\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.8.0)

Comment: @shlobb13 Did you try it from *Manage Packages* also?

Answer (score 0):

The error: No module named 'pyperclip', means the module is not installed correctly.

You can find more details of how to install third party module in Appendix A of the book.

I installed pyperclip successfully by typing "pip install --user pyperclip" in cmd, you can give it a try.

Comment: i did that already, just did it again and got the following msg: Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in c:\users\16463\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

First, **make sure you only use a single version of Python**, preferably the latest. It's possible that you have multiple versions installed and are using one for which the module was not installed.

> I seemingly installed the module successfully

To test this, **let's get the list of third-party packages you have installed**. open a command line and run `pip freeze -l`. Make sure pyperclip is indeed on the list.

- If it isn't on the list, try installing again (with `pip install pyperclip`).

  - If installation is confirmed to be successful, try using it again and it should work!
  - If installation fails, add the error message to the question and we'll see :)
- If it is on the list and yet you are getting `ModuleNotFoundError`, make sure pyperclip is spelled correctly. It could be the case that you had a typo during installation with pip, and installed, say, pyperclkp instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thonny uses its own Python interpreter by default. Unless you have changed the interpreter (Run => Select interpreter), Thonny's Python doesn't use c:\users\16463\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages

You should either install pyperclip to Thonny's bundled Python ("Tools => Manage packages" or "Tools => Open system shell") or make Thonny use your other Python ("Run => Select interpreter")